# Sorting a list with paths by deepest directory

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting, directory

I need to sort a list that contains paths (relative or absolute) so that the deepest path appears first, for example:

> \New Folder\Item1\tools\1
>   \New Folder\Item1\tools
>   \New Folder\Item1
>   \New Folder
>   etc...

Is there an API in `Path` class I can use to do it?

Thanks!
J.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bit out-of-the-box, but you could always do this:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderByDescending(
    p => p.Count(c => c == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
        || c == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar));
```

That is, simply order by how often the path separator character appears.

Comment: This is how I would do it, too!

Comment: This requires that all paths are absolute. Which is a good requirement since one never knows where the relative paths have been to.

Comment: Yeah, that's true - you may need to call Path.GetFullPath on each string and provide it with the "root" path that you know they all map to.

Comment: That works, but it would jumble the results if there is more than one root directory in the list.

Answer (score -1):

I assume those paths are strings, so why not just sort them in descending order?

```
var paths = new List<string>
{
  "\\New Folder",
  "\\New Folder\\tools",
  "\\Windows",
  "\\Windows\\System32",
  "\\New Folder\\tools\\1",
};

var result = paths.OrderByDescending(s => s);
```

Or if they are in a `string[]` you can use:

```
Array.Sort(paths);
Array.Reverse(paths);
```

Result is:

> \Windows\System32
>   \Windows
>   \New Folder\tools\1
>   \New Folder\tools
>   \New Folder

Comment: The problem is that \a\a\a\a will come last, when it should be first.